# iPhone Default Settings messing with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I work with responsive design and whenever I'm testing on androids my websites always look perfectly fine. However with iPhone's I notice there's a lot of default settings that mess with my coding big time. Border radius's coming up on inputs, certain text just blows up to big font's etc. I can never find where these are coming from using the inspect tool and since it's only on iPhone's I'm guessing it's default settings. I try to use "!important" for certain things but that never works. I was wondering if anyone else had these problems and know how to fix them? Am I missing a meta view?

Comment: Please provide examples of your code.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use !important to override default settings. I guess you want to override input or button style, what is the final result you expect? no border? no shading?